# is my bootloader working as expected? | x86_64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, bootloader, osdev

After a long time, I haven't tried a bootloader again and have done some tests and I think I've managed to write a bootloader for the first time that actually works. I can allow the a20 and load the bootloader and switch to protected mode. Now I have written the first kernel code which looks good and compiled it. Unfortunately when I tried to jump from bootloader to the kernel nothing happened. Since the OS doesn't smear in QEMU (I assume), the jump didn't go wrong, but it would be expected that we would have red pixels on the screen. can you take a look over it?

Here is the github link if it's easier for you:
[github](https://github.com/Fabbboy/vos/tree/feature/jump)

Bootloader.asm:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7c00]

BOOT_DRIVE equ 0x00
mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl

;; first step is to activate the A20 line
mov ax, 0x2401
int 0x15

;; next step is to correctly setup the stack
mov ax, 0x9000
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0xffff

;; now we can jump to the actual bootloader 
jmp bentry
;; here we could define variables for the bentry function
WELCOME_MSG db "Welcome to the bootloader!", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x00
LOADING_MSG db "Loading kernel...", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x00
DISK_ERROR_INT13 db "Error while performing int 0x13", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x00
DISK_ERROR_LOAD db "Error while loading kernel", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x00
FINISHED_MSG db "Kernel loaded!", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x00
FAILED_TO_LOAD_GDT db "Failed to load GDT", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x00
;; extern LOAD_KERNEL

;; Informations about the kernel
TARGET_KERNEL_ADDR dd 0x10000
KERNEL_SIZE equ 0x2000   
SECTOR_SIZE equ 0x200
SECTORS dw 0
HEAD db 0
CYLINDER db 0

bentry:
  mov si, WELCOME_MSG
  call print

  jmp .load_kernel
  jmp .stop

.load_kernel:
  mov si, LOADING_MSG
  call print

  call get_disk_info
  call calc_sectors
  call load_kernel

  mov si, FINISHED_MSG
  call print
  jmp .setupVideoMode
  jmp .enterProtectedMode
.setupVideoMode:
  mov ax, 0x4F02 ; VESA set mode function
  mov bx, 0x101  ; Mode number for 640x480x256
  int 0x10       ; Call BIOS
  jmp .enterProtectedMode

.enterProtectedMode:
  call switch_to_pm
  jmp halt

.stop:
  call halt


;;;;; Protected Mode ;;;;
GDT_start:
  GDT_null:
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0

  GDT_code:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0 
    db 0x0 
    db 0b10011010
    db 0b11001111
    db 0x0
  
  GDT_data:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0 
    db 0x0 
    db 0b10010010
    db 0b11001111
    db 0x0 
GDT_end:
CODE_SEG equ GDT_code - GDT_start
DATA_SEG equ GDT_data - GDT_start

GDT_DESC:
  dw GDT_end - GDT_start - 1
  dd GDT_start

switch_to_pm:
  cli
  lgdt [GDT_DESC]
  mov eax, cr0
  or eax, 0x1
  mov cr0, eax
  jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm    

[bits 32]
init_pm:
  mov ax, DATA_SEG
  mov ds, ax
  mov es, ax
  mov fs, ax
  mov gs, ax
  mov ss, ax
  mov esp, 0x90000
  mov ebp, 0x90000



  ;; draw a pixel on the screen
  jmp 0x8:TARGET_KERNEL_ADDR
  mov edi, 0xa0000
  mov ecx, 0x8000
  mov eax, 0x0f0000000
  rep stosd
  

  jmp $

;;;;; DISK FUNCTIONS ;;;
;; function to load the kernel 
load_kernel:
  mov ah, 0x02
  mov al, [SECTORS]
  mov ch, [CYLINDER]
  mov cl, 0x02
  mov dh, [HEAD]
  mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
  mov bx, TARGET_KERNEL_ADDR
  int 0x13
  jc .error

  jmp .wasKernelFound

  ret
.error:
  mov si, DISK_ERROR_LOAD
  call print
  jmp halt

.wasKernelFound:


;; utility function to obtain informations from bios about the disk
get_disk_info:
  mov ah, 0x08
  mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
  int 0x13
  jc .error
  mov [HEAD], dh
  ret
.error:
  mov si, DISK_ERROR_INT13
  call print
  jmp halt

;; utility function to calculate the number of sectors
calc_sectors:
  mov ax, [KERNEL_SIZE] 
  mov bx, [SECTOR_SIZE] 
  xor dx, dx          
  div bx              
  test dx, dx         
  jz .no_remainder     
  inc ax              
.no_remainder:
  mov [SECTORS], ax 
  ret



;;;;; UTILITY FUNCTIONS ;;;
;; utility function to print a string
print:  
  pusha
  mov ah, 0x0e
.loop:
  lodsb
  cmp al, 0
  je .done
  int 0x10
  jmp .loop
.done:
  popa
  ret

;; utility function to halt the system
halt:
  hlt
  jmp halt

;; bootloader padding
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

kernel.c:

```c
void start() __attribute__((noreturn));

void start() {
    unsigned char *fb = (unsigned char *) 0xA0000;
    for (int i = 0; i < 320 * 200; i++) {
        fb[i] = 0x04;
    }


    while (1) {}
}
```

linker.ld:

```
/* Linker Script for a 32-bit Kernel */

ENTRY(start)
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")

SECTIONS 
{
    /* Code Segment */
    .text 0x10000 : 
    {
        code = .;
        *(.text)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    /* Data Segment */
    .data : 
    {
        data = .;
        *(.data)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    /* BSS Segment */
    .bss : 
    {
        bss = .;
        *(.bss)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    /* End of Kernel */
    end = .;
}
```

kernel map:

```
Memory Configuration

Name             Origin             Length             Attributes
*default*        0x0000000000000000 0xffffffffffffffff

Linker script and memory map


.text           0x0000000000010000     0x1000
                0x0000000000010000                code = .
 *(.text)
 .text          0x0000000000010000       0x38 bin/object/c/./kernel.o
                0x0000000000010000                start
                0x0000000000011000                . = ALIGN (0x1000)
 *fill*         0x0000000000010038      0xfc8 

.note.gnu.property
                0x0000000000011000       0x20
 .note.gnu.property
                0x0000000000011000       0x20 bin/object/c/./kernel.o

.eh_frame       0x0000000000011020       0x38
 .eh_frame      0x0000000000011020       0x38 bin/object/c/./kernel.o

.data           0x0000000000011058      0xfa8
                0x0000000000011058                data = .
 *(.data)
 .data          0x0000000000011058        0x0 bin/object/c/./kernel.o
                0x0000000000012000                . = ALIGN (0x1000)
 *fill*         0x0000000000011058      0xfa8 

.bss            0x0000000000012000        0x0
                0x0000000000012000                bss = .
 *(.bss)
 .bss           0x0000000000012000        0x0 bin/object/c/./kernel.o
                0x0000000000012000                . = ALIGN (0x1000)
                0x0000000000012000                end = .
LOAD bin/object/c/./kernel.o
OUTPUT(bin/kernel.bin binary)

.comment        0x0000000000000000       0x2c
 .comment       0x0000000000000000       0x2c bin/object/c/./kernel.o

.note.GNU-stack
                0x0000000000000000        0x0
 .note.GNU-stack
                0x0000000000000000        0x0 bin/object/c/./kernel.o
```

makefile for kernel:

```
# Makefile for V-OS Kernel
# Author: @fabbboy

# Target architecture
TARGET_ARCH := x86_64-elf

# Compiler and Assembler setup
TARGET_CC := cc
TARGET_ASM := nasm
TARGET_LD := ld

# Flags for different file types
TARGET_ASMFLAGS := -f elf
TARGET_CFLAGS := -ffreestanding -nostdlib -I.
TARGET_LIBS := -L/usr/lib7gcc
TARGET_LINKFLAGS := -T linker.ld -nostdlib

# Directories
BUILD_DIR := ./bin
OBJ_DIR_C := $(BUILD_DIR)/object/c
OBJ_DIR_ASM := $(BUILD_DIR)/object/asm

# File finding
SOURCES_C := $(shell find ./ -type f -name '*.c')
SOURCES_ASM := $(shell find ./ -type f -name '*.asm')
OBJECTS_C := $(patsubst %.c, $(OBJ_DIR_C)/%.o, $(SOURCES_C))
OBJECTS_ASM := $(patsubst %.asm, $(OBJ_DIR_ASM)/%.o, $(SOURCES_ASM))

# Phony targets
.PHONY: all kernel clean

# Default target
all: kernel

# Kernel target
kernel: $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin

# Kernel binary
$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin: $(OBJECTS_ASM) $(OBJECTS_C)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    @$(TARGET_LD) $(TARGET_LINKFLAGS) --Map $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.map -o $@ $^ $(TARGET_LIBS)

    @echo "--> Created: kernel.bin"

# Compile C files
$(OBJ_DIR_C)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @$(TARGET_CC) $(TARGET_CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
    @echo "--> Compiled: " $<

# Compile ASM files
$(OBJ_DIR_ASM)/%.o: %.asm
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @$(TARGET_ASM) $(TARGET_ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    @echo "--> Compiled: " $<

# Clean target
clean:
    @rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*.bin $(OBJ_DIR_C)/*.o $(OBJ_DIR_ASM)/*.o
    @echo "--> Cleaned"
```

makefile for the bootlaoder:

```
CASM=nasm
CASMFLAGS=-f bin
CASMOUTPUT=bin/boot.bin
CASMINPUT=boot.S
LINKER=ld 
LINKERFLAGS= --oformat binary
IMAGE=bin/boot.img

all: clean boot.bin image 

boot.bin: boot.S
    @echo "Compiling bootloader..."
    @$(CASM) $(CASMFLAGS) $(CASMINPUT) -o $(CASMOUTPUT)
    @echo "Done."

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning..."
    @rm -f $(CASMOUTPUT)
    @echo "Done."

image:
    @echo "Creating floppy image..."
    @dd if=/dev/zero of=$(IMAGE) bs=1024 count=1440
    @dd if=$(CASMOUTPUT) of=$(IMAGE) conv=notrunc
    @echo "Done."

run:
    @echo "Running..."
    @qemu-system-i386 -fda $(IMAGE)
    @echo "Done."

.PHONY: all clean image run
```

root makefile:

```
# Root Makefile for V-OS Project

# Directories
BOOTLOADER_DIR := ./bootloader
KERNEL_DIR := ./kernel
IMAGE_DIR := ./bin
HDD_IMAGE := $(IMAGE_DIR)/vos.hdd

# Size of the hard disk image (in MB)
HDD_SIZE_MB := 10
SECTOR_SIZE := 512

# Phony targets
.PHONY: all bootloader kernel image clean

# Default target
all: bootloader kernel image

# Build bootloader
bootloader:
    @echo "Building bootloader..."
    @$(MAKE) -C $(BOOTLOADER_DIR)

# Build kernel
kernel:
    @echo "Building kernel..."
    @$(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR)

# Create hard disk image
image:
    @echo "Creating hard disk image..."
    @dd if=/dev/zero of=$(HDD_IMAGE) bs=1M count=$(HDD_SIZE_MB)
    @dd if=$(BOOTLOADER_DIR)/bin/boot.bin of=$(HDD_IMAGE) conv=notrunc
    @dd if=$(KERNEL_DIR)/bin/kernel.bin of=$(HDD_IMAGE) seek=1 conv=notrunc

# Clean up
clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up..."
    @$(MAKE) -C $(BOOTLOADER_DIR) clean
    @$(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) clean
    @rm -f $(HDD_IMAGE)
    @echo "Done."

run:
    @echo "Running..."
    @qemu-system-i386 -hda $(HDD_IMAGE)
    @echo "Done."
```

Comment: Do I understand you right in that the code works fine in QEMU but fails on real hardware?  Likely, this is related to you not leaving space for the BIOS Parameter Block in your boot sector.

Comment: no, so i dont know if it works because the kernel is not responding i dont think that the jump to the kernel succeeded

Comment: Try adding something that can definitely be noticed as the first instruction of the kernel.  E.g. you could start by clearing the screen or by playing a beep.